# Reading label settings with PyQGIS in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am struggling to read (with PyQGIS) even the most basic settings from a labeled shapefile in QGIS 3. I know this was pretty easy in QGIS 2 with `.readFromLayer` but it does not seem to work in QGIS 3. Is there another way that works in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**readFromLayer()** and **writeToLayer()** have been **removed**. Labeling is read/written in [QgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling.html) and its subclasses. [Backwards Incompatible Changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsPalLabeling)

To read the labels settings you can use this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
lab = layer.labeling()
palyr = lab.settings()
palyr.fieldName  # Print name of field (or an expression) to use for label text
palyr.displayAll # Print If true, all features will be labelled even when overlaps occur.
```

Api reference [QgsPalLayerSettings](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#ac57b3ecf3c052e33c947ed8713e4b48c)

Comment: Thanks, just the thing i was looking for.